# findViewById returning null

Tags: android, null, findviewbyid

I have this Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.ui.library.actionbar.ActionBar
        android:id="@+id/actionBar1"
        style="@style/ActionBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <com.cidaut.moveo.calendar.ui.calendar.SingleCalendar
        android:id="@+id/singleCalendar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/actionBar1" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/dark_gray" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonFiltros"
            style="@style/MetroButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="8dip"
            android:text="@string/filter" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Everything works as expected. However, when I call `findViewById` in my `Activity` to find `R.id.singleCalendar1`, it returns null.

I've tried cleaning and updating to no avail.

I thought of inflating the view using `LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.id.calendar_layout, null)`, finding its children, and then finding singleCalendar1 ID...

[image: -1!]

I really don't know what to do. Any hindsight is pretty much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the activity's code as well? (at least the onCreate)

Comment: what is com.cidaut.moveo.calendar.ui.calendar.SingleCalendar?

Comment: you should use the correct package name for accessing your custom calender,action bar etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I have an idea what's going on here... maybe it's a part of the dialog thats effing with you?

Suppose something like this

```
 Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
 setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
 findViewById(R.id.my_view); //doesn't work
```

try this

```
 Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
 setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
 View v = (View) d.findViewById(R.id.my_view); //will work
```

Try referencing from the parent. Or please post more code where this layout is being pulled-in / used.

Also, do you have a proper constructor for the single calendar object?

You need this one

```
AndroidObject(Context context, AttribSet attrs);
```

which will call super(context, attrs);

maybe that fixes it.

Comment: The constructor was calling a custom constructor which was calling super(context), that's why it didn't work. Thank you!

Comment: Remember kids, ALWAYS PROVIDE ALL THREE CONSTRUCTORS. Android is broken that way.

Answer (score 0):

For inflating use this piece of code

```
LayoutInflater inflaterLayoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout=inflaterLayoutInflater.inflate(R.id.calendar_layout,null);
```

Otherwise just check weather u have set the correct layout in setCOntentView if ur using it normally .